# TensorFlow: How to get Intermediate value of a variable in tf.while_loop()?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to fetch the intermediate value of a tensor in tf.while_loop(), however, it only gives me the last returned value.

For example, I have a variable x, which has 3 pages and its dimension is 3*2*4. Now I want to fetch each page one time and calculate the total sum, the page sum, the mean, max and min value of each page. Then I define the condition and body function and want to use tf.while_loop() to calculate the needed results. The source code is as bellow.

```
import tensorflow as tf    
x = tf.constant([[[41, 8, 48,  82],
                      [9, 56, 67,  23]],
                     [[95, 89, 44,  54],
                      [11, 33, 29,  1]],
                     [[34,  9,  5,  70],
                      [14, 35, 18,  17]]], dtype=tf.int32)

def cond(out, count, x):
  return count < 3

def body(out, count, x):
  outTemp = tf.slice(x, [count, 0, 0], [1, -1, -1])
  count += 1
  outPack = tf.unpack(out)
  outPack[0] += tf.reduce_sum(outTemp)
  outPack[1] = tf.reduce_sum(outTemp)
  outPack[2] = tf.reduce_mean(outTemp)
  outPack[3] = tf.reduce_max(outTemp)
  outPack[4] = tf.reduce_min(outTemp)
  out = tf.pack(outPack)
  return out, count, x

out = tf.Variable(tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))  # total sum, page sum, mean, max, min
count = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0))
result = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [out, count, x])

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  print(sess.run(x))
  print(sess.run(result)[0])
```

When I run the program, it only gives me the returned value of the last time and I can only get the results of the last page.
So the question is, How can I get the results of each page and How can I get the intermediate value from tf.while_loop()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "intermediate value" of any variable, you can simply make use of the tf.Print op which really is an identity operation with the side effect of printing a relevant message when evaluating the aforementioned variable.

As an example,

```
x = tf.Print(x, [x], "Value of x is: ")
```

Can be placed in any line where you want the value to be reported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know, where will you put the tf.Print()? In fact, when I put it in the function body(), it does not work and print any result. Since the tf.while_loop() function was executed in a special way.

Comment: That's strange. Can you paste your body function here?

Comment: Hi, all my code has been pasted when I asked the question and you can have a look in the question sections. Thank you again.